# An error occurs in Pandas Indexing.('A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I asked you this question because I have a small question about Pandas Indexing.

this is my data

```
df['f5'][:10]

10    98.429899
97    98.429899
9     98.429899
76    98.429899
98    97.381034
91    97.381034
86    97.381034
71    97.381034
11    91.297791
19    91.297791
```

I want to change the 10 data in the 'f5' column to a specific value without reset_index() (while maintaining the index).

```
df['f5'][:10] = 91.29779092  #o
df.loc[:,'f5'][:10] = 91.29779092 #o
df[:10]['f5'] = 91.29779092  #x
df.iloc[:10,]['f5'] = 91.29779092 #x
```

As you can see, the value of O changed well, but X did not change well, so I wonder why.

And all of this
'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame,' warns Pandas.
So I'm thinking about what indexing Pandas wants, but I can't figure it out in my head.

After reset_index()->df.loc[:9,'f5'] , what is the other way to keep the index and not get a panda warning? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you index is non duplicated, you can try mixed indexing:

```
df.loc[d.index[:10], 'f5'] = 91.29779092
```

Alternatively:

```
df.iloc[:10, df.columns.get_loc('f5')] = 91.29779092
```

Comment: I was really a beginner at Pandas.
Both work very well.